# "Considered to be cheap" vs. "considered a cheap person" vs. "considered as a cheap person" vs. "considered cheap"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Today on Quora I came across this sentence "he is considered to be cheap". So my question is can I modify the sentence in following ways:

> 1. He is considered a cheap person.
> 2. He is considered as a cheap person.
> 3. He is considered cheap.

So which of these is appropriate to use in place of "**considered to be**"?

And lastly, what is the exact meaning of considered to be?

Comment: #1 or #3 is fine, but #2 sounds wrong to this US English speaker - something is "considered <noun>" not "considered *as* <noun>".

Comment: #2 is also wrong to uk speaker.

Comment: So what is the exact difference between: A. Considered To be (noun) and B. Considered (noun)?

Comment: @kuldeepsharma - Be careful; neither of your first three examples uses "Considered...<noun>" - *cheap* is an adjective.

Comment: It is just 'considered', and not 'considered to be', which means in standard English one doesn't use 'to be' after 'consider'.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "considered to be cheap"

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cheap

> North American informal Miserly. ‘she's too cheap to send me a postcard’
>   but I would say it is a Brit English word as well now.

So other example sentences:
"don't be so cheap it is only an icecream"

I have gone for miserly as it is a single meaning word whereas cheap has multiple meanings
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/miserly

> adj greedy, stingy, tightfisted, abject, cheapskate,
>   parsimonious penny-pinching penurious skinflint sordid ungenerous

So if somebody **"cheap"** took you out for a meal you know it would be the cheapest restaurant in town, or somewhere he had enough discount tokens to make it very inexpensive.

And I thought this article just looked interesting on the subject

> https://www.investopedia.com/financial-edge/0412/how-to-tell-if-youre-cheap-or-frugal.aspx

Comment: Somebody can be cheap, yes, but I would not say X is a cheap person, usually.